# Aarch64 Python 3.9 Liniux Miniconda fails to install on Aarch64 Python 3.9 Linux... it's looking for an .exe?

Tags: python, miniconda

I'm very unclear on why the official Miniconda ***Linux*** installer for Aarch64 is failing with an error about trying to find a non-existent ***.exe***...

```
Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
>>> yes

Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/pi/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/pi/miniconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/pi/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
./Miniconda3-py39_23.3.1-0-Linux-aarch64.sh: 352: /home/pi/miniconda3/conda.exe: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

That (`conda.exe`) is what it should have named an executable that it extracts a few lines before that, see the extract from the .sh file (https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_23.3.1-0-Linux-aarch64.sh, lines 340-352):

```
# the first binary payload: the standalone conda executable
CONDA_EXEC="$PREFIX/conda.exe"
extract_range "${boundary0}" "${boundary1}" > "$CONDA_EXEC"
chmod +x "$CONDA_EXEC"

export TMP_BACKUP="${TMP:-}"
export TMP="$PREFIX/install_tmp"
mkdir -p "$TMP"

# the second binary payload: the tarball of packages
printf "Unpacking payload ...\n"
extract_range $boundary1 $boundary2 | \
    "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --extract-tarball --prefix "$PREFIX"
```

For some reason, on your system the first part creating the `.exe` file fails. I would check if you have enough disk_space and permission on the target folder. Make also sure it is empty

Comment: Thanks. I was off-base about the .exe being "wrong" then, but I didn't realize that .exe's were used on Linux like this? That part was suspicious to me, but I guess it's by design. However I still need to resolve the issue. I just checked and it's not the disk space. It was run with `sudo` but I will investigate permissions further.

Comment: @Hack-R you're right that `.exe` has no special meaning on Unix systems like it does on Windows - it's just a filename like any other. In this case, it happens the Conda standalone devs decided to emit a `conda.exe` as the name for the binary on all platforms. I used to [recommend this standalone to users for repairing broken Conda installs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54563455/10), and would deliberately have users rename it to `conda-exec` simply to avoid the cognitive dissonance. (Now I recommend Micromamba, BTW).